# why is the scheduler run in two time in scheduled time

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

In my spring boot application, I have written a scheduler to sync some details at the scheduled time.
I have deployed my spring boot application in a Linux server with the Tomcat server. My Linux
server is in UTC time.

My problem is I've noticed my scheduler run two times that I scheduled time. I will mention the log details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz1ts.png)

As you can see there are two "ClassLink sync Starting." messages with different trace Ids.
Bellow, I'll mention my scheduler code also.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30 2 * * *", zone = "UTC")
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask2() throws Exception {
    String traceId = controllerUtil.generateTracerId();
    log.info(MessageConstants.API_LOG_INFO,traceId, LocalDateTime.now(), "ClassLink sync Starting." );
    //classLinkService.fetchClassLinkData(traceId);
    log.info(MessageConstants.API_LOG_INFO,traceId, LocalDateTime.now(), "ClassLink sync finished." );
}
```

Please not that Linux server doesn't have docker or multiple instances. Just installed tomact server to Linux environment and deploy the soring boot WAR file in tomcat server

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: well, are you having any other scheduler methods? i noticed you are calling your method `scheduleFixedDelayTask2()`. is the duplicated log coming from any `scheduleFixedDelayTask()` or something?

Comment: I have another scheduler task inside of a different controller.  other scheduler calling a different method with different logs. and scheduled time is different